# Not able to install React native cli app over app built previously with expo cli

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-cli

I have installed a react-native app built with expo cli from playstore, I am migrating to react-native cli. I am not able to install the react-native cli build(signed with the same android key) over the existing expo build. I am getting the following error

> App not installed, the package conflicts with an existing package by
>   same name

any solution will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Expo and React-native cli are two different things , as i am too implementing both in single app , after that my app start crashing so you can only use one cli at a moment .

here are the difference and merits -demerits of both .

**React Native init**:

***Merits:***

You can add native modules written in Java/Objective-C (probably the only but the strongest one)

***Demerits:***

Needs Android Studio and X Code to run the projects
You can't develop for iOS without having a mac
Device has to be connected via USB to use it for testing
Fonts need to be imported manually in X Code
If you want to share the app you need to send the whole .apk / .ipa file
Does not provide JS APIs out of the box, e.g. Push-Notifications, Asset Manager, they need to be manually installed and linked with npm for example
Setting up a working project properly (including device configuration) is rather complicated and can take time

**Expo:**

***Merits:***

Setting up a project is easy and can be done in minutes
You (and other people) can open the project while you're working on it
Sharing the app is easy (via QR-code or link), you don't have to send the whole .apk or .IPA file
No build necessary to run the app
Integrates some basic libraries in a standard project (Push Notifications, Asset Manager,...)
You can eject it to Expo Kit and integrate native code continuing using some of the Expo features, but not all of them
Expo can build .apk and .ipa files (distribution to stores possible with Expo)

***Demerits:***

You can't add native modules (probably a game changer for some)
You can't use libraries that use native code in Objective-C/Java
The standard Hello World app is about 25MB big (because of the integrated libraries)
If you want to use: Face Detector, Ar Kit o Payments you need to eject it to Expo Kit
Ejecting it to Expo Kit has a trade-off of features of Expo, e.g. you cannot share via QR code
When ejecting to Expo Kit you are limited to the react native version that is supported by Expo Kit at that point in time
Debugging in Expo Kit (with native modules) is a lot more complicated, since it mixes two languages and different libraries (no official Expo support anymore)
And you can use any one which satisfies your applications requirement.

Hope it will make you understand the difference between these two Clis.

Comment: yes , sure please install one cli at time expo or react-native.